# Proof that the commutator of angular momentum and 4-momentum is 0

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, metric-tensor, commutator, poincare-symmetry

I have this commutator $[P^2,J_{\mu\nu}]$ that I'm supposed to prove is zero. If we expand it (given that $[P_{\alpha}, J_{\mu\nu}] = i(g_{\mu\alpha}P_{\nu} - g_{\nu\alpha}P_{\mu})$ and $[P_{\alpha}, P_{\beta}] = 0$) we end up with $$[P^2,J_{\mu\nu}] = [P_{\alpha}P_{\alpha},J_{\mu\nu}] = i(P_{\alpha}g_{\mu\alpha}P_{\nu} - P_{\alpha}g_{\nu\alpha}P_{\mu} + g_{\mu\alpha}P_{\nu}P_{\alpha} - g_{\nu\alpha}P_{\mu}P_{\alpha}).$$

This is supposed to be zero, but how do I prove it? If all indices are equal, or if all are different, because we are using Minkowski metric, this is straightforward. But for example in the case where $\mu=\alpha\neq\nu$, we end up with $$[P^2,J_{\mu\nu}] = [P_{\alpha}P_{\alpha},J_{\mu\nu}] = i(P_{\alpha}g_{\mu\alpha}P_{\nu} + g_{\mu\alpha}P_{\nu}P_{\alpha}).$$
How do I prove this is zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have written,

$$[P^2,J_{\mu\nu}] = [P_{\alpha}P_{\alpha},J_{\mu\nu}] = i(P_{\alpha}g_{\mu\alpha}P_{\nu} - P_{\alpha}g_{\nu\alpha}P_{\mu} + g_{\mu\alpha}P_{\nu}P_{\alpha} - g_{\nu\alpha}P_{\mu}P_{\alpha}).$$

The $\alpha$ here is summed over, per the Einstein summation convention; I would really write it as, $$P^2 = P^\alpha P_\alpha = g^{\alpha\beta}P_\alpha P_\beta.$$ So the right hand side reduces to $i(2P_\mu P_\nu - 2P_\mu P_\nu) =0$. Always remember "conservation of indices." (There are some exceptions in some notational conventions.) Your left hand side is $[P^2,J_{\mu\nu}]$, there is no $\alpha$ index, so there is no free $\alpha$ index allowed on the right hand side either.